# Check box is not being shown on form

Tags: javascript

I am working on WordPress Wofunnels form.I am writing code to get input with checkbox. Here is the problem.
The label has been displayed but check is not getting displayed.

```
< script >
    setTimeout(function () {
        var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
        x.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");

        x.checked = true;
        var label = document.createElement('label')
        label.htmlFor = "id";
        label.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Do you want to include this product?'));

        document.getElementsByClassName('wfacp_order_summary_container')[0].appendChild(x);
        document.getElementsByClassName('wfacp_order_summary_container')[0].appendChild(label);

    }, 8000); <
/script>
```

https://varycare.com/checkouts/jv1/?preview_id=529&preview_nonce=d4e329e985&preview=true

Comment: I see an "<" at the end, which might be causing the issue. It works as expected.

Comment: Issue is not due to extra extra "<". Please open this link where code is pasted. It's only working for label.

Comment: https://varycare.com/checkouts/jv1/?preview_id=529&preview_nonce=d4e329e985&preview=true

Comment: getting an error when try to access the url "Sorry, you are not allowed to preview drafts."

Answer (score 1):

I have added the code in fiddle, removed the extra "<" it's working as expected.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
  x.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");

  x.checked = true;
  var label = document.createElement('label')
  label.htmlFor = "id";
  label.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Do you want to include this product?'));

  document.getElementsByClassName('wfacp_order_summary_container')[0].appendChild(x);
  document.getElementsByClassName('wfacp_order_summary_container')[0].appendChild(label);

}, 8000);
```

```html
<div class='wfacp_order_summary_container'>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nishantj/rwgqkvaz/1/